# tvw control look for childs

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a tree view control in a access form and I'm wondering how I can see if a selected node has a child associated with it. I know how to get to selected node:

```
Forms!Home.tvwLOBTTrees.SelectedItem
```

but I can't seem to find what the properties of SelectedItem is. For instance...

```
Forms!Home.tvwLOBTTrees.SelectedItem.child
```

does not exist.

I'm thinking that something like haveing an if statement for this...so if I could figure out how to count the number of children of the selected node, then do something. So something like this:

```
chldCnt = Forms!Home.tvwLOBTTrees.SelectedItem.children.count

if chldCnt > 0 then
    do this
else
    do this
end if
```

Comment: Which tree view control are you using?

Comment: @ChipsLetten I'm using MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2

Comment: From what I can see the SelectedItem property returns a Node, and SelectedItem.Children should give you the number of children of the node.

Comment: late response here but I've tried Forms!Home.tvwCntrl.SelectedItem.Children and get a "Application-defined or object-defined error."